# Post object in postman which contains arraylist of other object which contains MultiPartFile

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, post, postman, backend

I have an object which contains a list of other object. The other object contains multipartfile attribute.

```
public class Topic {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("components")
    List<DataComponents> components;
    @JsonProperty("tags")
    List<String> tags;
}

public class DataComponents {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;
    @JsonProperty("Description")
    String Description;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    String type;
    @JsonProperty("file")
    MultipartFile file;
    @JsonProperty("url")
    String url;
}
```

If I want to post this Topic object from postman, How can I do that, because DataComponents object is having mutipartfile.

Comment: Can you share the request as a CURL command?

Comment: Actually I am new to development field. What is CURL command?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pictorial form of sending data along with image.

**NOTE: This screenshot was taken from old chrome extension version of POSTMAN. But same you can refer for new POSTMAN too.**

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: If the metapartfile attribute is directly in the main object, I can follow this. But in my case it is present in nested form, that too in an object whose list is the attribute in main object class.